# Nginx centos 8 Map Multiple Lumen Projects to Single Domain

Tags: laravel, nginx, lumen, nginx-config, centos8

I have 6 Lumen Projects which was working fine on apache centos. I just reconfigured server to nginx. I was able to setup single project in nginx config but cannot figure out how to setup multiple directories i tried several configs but not working. Here is my nginx config
**PS: before mark it as duplicate please try to explain & help me to fix this issue**

```
 server {
        root /var/www/domain.com/html/api/gateway/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    location / {
        autoindex on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;         
    }
    #    location /search {
    #               autoindex on;
    #       root /var/www/domain.com/html/api/search/public;
    #       index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    #        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    #        }
    location  ~ \.php$ {    
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size on;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }
    server {
        if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

This is working fine but when i uncomment search config section it stops working both of them throw forbidden or sometimes 404 error